# Run python program from webpage

Tags: python-3.x, html

I have a python program on an Ubuntu 16 server that I'd like my co-workers to be able to run from their desktops without logging into the server. I'd like to have a small webpage they could use to run the code from one or two button presses and also upload an input file to be used. The site would be reachable only through local network.

I tried some searching over the past weeks but there's so much information. Any direction towards something known to do solve a similar problem would be great.

Comment: You could use something like flask

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

Comment: Thanks! I messed around with flask and I think I can use it, plus a database, to get what I want done.